# nHow to work out the spanning tree of an acyclic graph in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I need to calculate the spanning tree of an acyclic graph implemented on OrientDB. The spanning tree I’m looking for is built such as only the longest paths leading from the root to a branch or leaf should be kept. For instance, if you have the choice between a direct link (edge) between the tree root & a given branch and a second path traversing several branches between the same root and the same branch, only the latter path (the edges) should be kept to build the final tree (a spanning tree :).

How can I calculate this spanning tree in OrientDB ? Is there a similar function to ShortestPath() or dijkstra() in OrientDB to do it in an easy way ?  Many thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

A.  Worker

Comment: Coul you explain better what you want ? Do you want select some paths and delete other paths ?

Comment: Hi Alessandro, Exactly, I need to filter out from an acyclic graph any path leading from the root to the branches or leaves when there exists an alternative longest path from the root to the same branches or leaves.

Comment: More precisely,  I need to filter out from a directed acyclic graph any edge leading from a vertex to another vertex when there exists an alternative longest path (traversing several edges) from the same two vertex and this for every pair of vertex to eventually obtain the spanning tree of the directed acyclic graph.

Comment: Do you want it in javascript or in a java ?

Comment: My preference would be in OrientDB SQL if that can be done. Otherwhise as an OrientDB function written in javascript. This would be good too though I have never tried implementing functions in ODB so far. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: To the down voters ... please provide a comment as to why you down voted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In java, you could use this similar code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Direction;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;

public class LongestPath {

    private boolean stop=false;
    private Vertex vertex_from=null;
    private List<Vertex> vertexPreviousStep=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    private List<Vertex> vertexCurrently=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    private List<List<Vertex>> paths=new ArrayList<List<Vertex>>();
    private OrientGraph g;

    public LongestPath(OrientGraph g) {
        this.g=g;
    }

    protected List<Vertex> getPath(String rid_from, String rid_to) {
        if(!checkIfExistsNodes(rid_from,rid_to))
            return new ArrayList<Vertex>();

        vertexPreviousStep.add(vertex_from);

        List<Vertex> p=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        Vertex from=g.getVertex(rid_from);
        Vertex to=g.getVertex(rid_to);
        p.add(from);
        paths.add(p);

        int step=1;
        do{
            stop=false;
            for(Vertex v: vertexPreviousStep){
                Vertex rid_previousVertex=v;
                List<Vertex> rid_toAdd=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
                Iterable<Vertex> nodes = (Iterable<Vertex>) v.getVertices(Direction.OUT);
                for(Vertex v1:nodes){
                    rid_toAdd.add(v1);
                    String rid=v1.getId().toString();
                    if(!rid.equals(rid_to))  // non sono arrivato al nodo finale
                        vertexCurrently.add(v1);
                }
                if(rid_toAdd.size()!=0)
                    setPaths(rid_previousVertex,rid_toAdd,step);
            }
            change();
            step++;
        }while(stop==true);
        cleanPaths(to);
        return getLongestPath();
    }

    private boolean checkIfExistsNodes(String rid_from,String rid_to) {
        boolean find_from=false;
        boolean find_to=false;
        for(Vertex v:g.getVertices()){
            if(v.getId().toString().equals(rid_from)){
                find_from=true;
                vertex_from=v;
            }
            else if(v.getId().toString().equals(rid_to))
                find_to=true;
        }
        if(find_from==false || find_to==false)
            return false; 
        return true;
    }

    public void change(){
        vertexPreviousStep.clear();
        for(Vertex v:vertexCurrently)
            vertexPreviousStep.add(v);
        vertexCurrently.clear();
    }

    private void setPaths(Vertex previousVertex,List<Vertex> rid_toAdd,int step) {
        for(int i=0;i<paths.size();i++){
            List<Vertex> list=paths.get(i);
            Vertex last=list.get(list.size()-1);
            if(last.getId().toString().equals(previousVertex.getId().toString()) && list.size()==step){  
                int j=0;
                for(Vertex rid:rid_toAdd){
                    boolean rid_found=false;
                    for(Vertex p:list){
                        if(p.equals(rid))
                            rid_found=true; 
                    }
                    if(rid_found==false){
                        List<Vertex> p2=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
                        for(Vertex p:list)
                            p2.add(p);
                        p2.add(rid);
                        if(j==0){
                            stop=true;
                            paths.set(i, p2);
                            j++;
                        }
                        else
                            paths.add(p2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    public void cleanPaths(Vertex to){
        for(int i=0;i<paths.size();i++){
            List<Vertex> list=paths.get(i);
            if(!list.get(list.size()-1).equals(to)){
                paths.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Vertex> getLongestPath(){
        if(paths.size()==0)
            return new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        else{
            List<Vertex> list=paths.get(0);
            int max_size= list.size();
            for(int i=1;i<paths.size();i++){
                if(paths.get(i).size()>max_size){
                    max_size=paths.get(i).size();
                    list=paths.get(i);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    OrientGraph g=new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/39697129"); 
    LongestPath longest= new LongestPath(g);
    String id_vertex_from="#9:0";
    String id_vertex_to="#10:1";
    List<Vertex> list=longest.getPath(id_vertex_from,id_vertex_to);
    System.out.println(list);
    g.shutdown();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alessandro for your answer in Java. I would need a solution in ODB SQL or in javascript integrated as a function in ODB. Besides this, the solution you suggest is only for the longuest path between two vertex in a graph. Using this solution for every pair of vertex to calculate a spanning tree is not optimal in terms of complexity. A spanning tree algorithm is of complexity 0(N).

Comment: If you want a new ODB SQL , could you open a request on github ?

Comment: Hi Alessandro, I'll open a request on github. I definitely think this feature may be of help to the ODB community. If in the meanwhile I found a workaround based on ODB SQL, I'll post it here :-) Many thanks for your help! Cheers, Allein Worker